# Modularity in Excel - calculation "blocks"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have quite a complex Excel calculating the expenses of a project. A simplified, English (by popular demand :) sample is:

[image]

The formulas take as input the two values A and B, and are controlled by the two control flags A and B. **Each** combination of the values and flags results in a different result.

Now, what I would like to see are the different results for the different sets of values and controls.

One way, of course, would be to set the values, write down the result. Change the values, write down the result. Change the values, write down the result. Change the values, write down the result.

You get the picture? Tedious.

**So, the question is: How can I do the same calculation for different input values??**

**Edit**: Due to popular demand I've created a simplified sample. The problem is that this leads to answers that might not take into consideration the complexity of the problem. To get a taste of the problem, look at this previous **real-life description** [**here**](https://superuser.com/revisions/1438083/6).

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that this is framed like a general discussion topic rather than a specific problem to be solved.  Present it as a specific problem with an example, including your unsatisfactory solution, and ask how to solve that problem without redundancy.

Comment: It sounds like User Defined Functions might be the way to go.  How's your VBA?  :-)

Comment: Rusty (i.e. decades), but can do

Comment: Your definition of the problem is much too vague. Please include in the post a (simple) version of your spreadsheet, with column names so we can all discuss the same thing. Demonstrate also the kind of manipulation that you wish to achieve.

Comment: The edit is a step in the right direction, but it is still hard for people to respond to.  Everything is in Hebrew except for the numbers, so it is hard for people to know what they're looking at or to be able to refer to specific things.  You sort of describe the nature of the numbers, but your objective is to  modularize, and people will need to see the formulas to do anything useful with that.  As-is, this is too vague to generate useful responses.  My impression is that the task is too big for the intended scope of a question, other than some very generic advice.

Comment: Yes, this won't do at all. Better create a simplified version in English of *very few columns* and dummy data.

Comment: I would recommend buying expense management software. You could spend countless hours trying to build a cheap version in Excel and it would cost more than just buying software that is known to work.

Comment: Scenario Manager kind of does what you are asking, but you have to put in all the permutations you want to try manually.

Comment: @Avi: If you don't do the effort of giving a simple example in English, you won't get an answer.

Comment: Just add blocks where the potential changes and their effects are listed? Unless I'm missing something critical, what you're trying to do is extremely trivial - just add the formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the answer is an [Excel Data Table](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/create-an-excel-data-table-to-compare-multiple-results/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as powerful as Excel is, it is still spreadsheet software.  There are Excel add-ins, Business Intelligence tools, and full-fledged database softwares built for the kind of reporting analytics you are trying to do.

There are ways of forcing Excel to do it (as you suggested in a previous edit, making it duplicate on the fly, and risk waking [Codethulu](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Call_of_Codethulhu) with endless permutations), but if you're looking to see how changing values "affects the result," then you need to be using a different toolset.

Comment: What the poster is asking for is standard spreadsheet practice. The only problem we have is understanding what exactly he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, I would suggest doing the following:

1. Create one instance of a group of the five cells with their formulas:

[image]

2. Select the five cells.
3. Position the cursor to the lower right-hand corner of the bottom cell.
   You’ll know you have hit it when the cursor changes to a plus sign.
4. Click and drag to the right, filling as many columns as you need
   (12 columns in all for your example).
   This will also duplicate the formulas, but will correct the cell references so
   that each copy refers to its own cells.
5. Enter the values for the other 11 occurrences and otherwise modify the
   spreadsheet as you like.

If this answer is not what your are looking for, maybe because your real case
is more complicated than your example, please give more details.

Comment: Thank you. However, the calculation part is about 10X70 cells large. There are 10 control variables and flags, and about 20 input values. This scale makes the "duplication" solution less than desirable.

Comment: I understand better your difficulties in describing the problem. With all of those variables and input values, what is the result - one number or more? You could maybe use VBA to write all values to a file, or maybe create dynamically a new spreadsheet with all the results.

Comment: Such VBA is not too complicated, but the requirements need to be known.